# Are separate intent services queued on the same thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, android-intentservice

I have two intent services - `IntentServiceA` and `IntentServiceB`

They have the following class definitions:

```
public class FirstService extends IntentService {
  public FirstService() {
      super("first_service");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      Log.d("chi6rag", "first starts");
      for (long i = 0l; i < 10000000l; i++) {
          if (i == 0l) Log.d("chi6rag", "first started");
      }
      Log.d("chi6rag", "first ends");
  }
}
```

and

```
public class SecondService extends IntentService {
  public SecondService() {
      super("second_service");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      Log.d("chi6rag", "second starts");
      for (long i = 0l; i < 10000000l; i++) {
          if (i == 0l) Log.d("chi6rag", "second started");
      }
      Log.d("chi6rag", "second ends");
  }
}
```

If I execute the following code in my Activity:

`startService(new Intent(this, IntentServiceA.class));`

`startService(new Intent(this, IntentServiceB.class));`

I see the following printed in my logs:

`D/chi6rag (11734): first starts`

`D/chi6rag (11734): first started`

`D/chi6rag (11734): second starts`

`D/chi6rag (11734): second started`

`D/chi6rag (11734): first ends`

`D/chi6rag (11734): second ends`

While if one sees the Intent Service Docs, it clearly mentions that it passes `one intent at a time` to `onHandleIntent` method of the IntentService

Question: Is there a separate worker thread for each and every intent service? because the expected logs are:

`D/chi6rag (11734): first starts`

`D/chi6rag (11734): first started`

`D/chi6rag (11734): first ends`

`D/chi6rag (11734): second starts`

`D/chi6rag (11734): second started`

`D/chi6rag (11734): second ends`

Comment: every `IntentService` uses an own `HandlerThread` to serve requests, so if you have two `IntentService`s there are two separate `HandlerThread`s

Comment: "one intent at a time" -- provided those intents are both directed to the same `IntentService`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IntentService does the following:

> 1. Creates a default worker thread that executes all intents delivered      to onStartCommand() separate from your application's
>      main thread.
> 2. Creates a **work queue** that passes one intent at a time to your       onHandleIntent() implementation, so you never have to worry about
>      multi-threading
> 3. Provides a default implementation of onStartCommand() that sends the
>      intent to the work queue and then to your onHandleIntent()
>      implementation.

Since you have multiple classes extended form IntentService which each has their own specific onHandleIntent. These are handled on separate work queues.

See [Extending the Intentservice](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docs: [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

AFAIK, all the request will be handled on a single thread `per IntentService`. That means if you create many `IntentService`s, there is no guarantee that which `IntentService`'s thread is executed first.

If you want to run many threads or do work sequentially in a single thread, try to play `ExecutorService` with `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and `runnable` as in the [ExecutorService Examples](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)